# Как добавлять класс к пункту меню при одном чанке MODX Revo

Tags: modx

Есть меню, которое используется на всех страницах сайта:

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='item [[*active]]'>Страница 1</li>
  <li class='item'>Страница 2</li>
  <li class='item'>Страница 3</li>
  <li class='item'>Страница 4</li>
</ul>
```

Как с помощью TV изменять [[*active]] на выбранной странице. Например при переходе на страницу 4, [[*active]] должен перемещаться к четвертой странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас небольшое статическое меню, то для каждого пункта можно прописать следующее(и я не вижу, зачем здесь нужен TV) - здесь вы сравниваете ID текущей страницы с заданными ID:

```
<li class='item [[*id:isequalto=`5`:then=`active`]]'>Страница 5</li>
```

Если же у вас большое меню, удобно использовать например [pdoTools](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/pdoTools) и уже внутри в соответствующем чанке сравнивать значение переменной [[+id]], которая содержит в себе ID страницы к выводу, с id текущей активной страницы.

```
<li class='item [[*id:isequalto=`[[+id]]`:then=`active`]]'>Страница такая то</li>
```

Comment: Воспользовался pdoTools. Спасибо!